# JQuery Clone() mangles my html. Alternatives to be able to copy the same code several times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page using JQuery UI's tab widget. 2 of those tabs share the same piece of HTML, which is nothing more than a simple HTML table:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="showTable" id="table-person-info">
    <tr>
        <td class="pictureColumn">
            <img alt="Person Photo" src="images/avatar.jpg" id="CurrPersonPhoto" />
        </td>                   
        <td>
            <div id="CurrPersonFullName" class="fullName"></div>
            <b class="popupInfo">Person ID:&nbsp;</b><div id="CurrPersonID" class="popupInfo"></div><br />
            <b class="popupInfo">Hire Date:&nbsp;</b><div id="CurrHireDate" class="popupInfo"></div><br />
            <b class="popupInfo">Tenure:&nbsp;</b><div id="CurrTenure" class="popupInfo"></div><br />
            <b class="popupInfo">Location:&nbsp;</b><div id="CurrLocation" class="popupInfo"></div>
        </td>
        <td style="width:179px;">
            <img src="edit.png" alt="Edit" />
            <img src="log_activity.png" alt="Log activity" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The table gets updated after an ajax call, and to avoid having to repeat the same code twice, I tried to use the JQuery clone() function to be able to inject it to the 2 spots on the tabs where I need to show it. I used this call:

```
$("#table-person-info").clone(false).find("*").removeAttr("id").appendTo($("#person-Info-View"));
```

Changing the parameter of the clone method from true to false did not seem to make any difference. What I found is that this code completely mangles the html code to something like this:

```
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="showTable">    </table>
    <tr>
        <td class="pictureColumn">
        </td>                   
        <td>
        </td>
        <td style="width:179px;">
            <img src="edit.png" alt="Edit" />
            <img src="log_activity.png" alt="Log activity" />
        </td>
    </tr>
<img alt="Person Photo" src="images/avatar.jpg" />
<div id="CurrPersonFullName" class="fullName"></div>
<b class="popupInfo">Person ID:&nbsp;</b><div class="popupInfo"></div><br />
<b class="popupInfo">Hire Date:&nbsp;</b><div class="popupInfo"></div><br />
<b class="popupInfo">Tenure:&nbsp;</b><div class="popupInfo"></div><br />
<b class="popupInfo">Location:&nbsp;</b><div class="popupInfo"></div>
```

A quick review to the JQuery documentation shows that this is actually expected, I quote:

> When using .clone() to clone a collection of elements that are not attached to the DOM, their order when inserted into the DOM is not guaranteed

That being the case then, what kind of alternative do I have? am I condem to duplicate the table and just update the values manually every time the tab is selected? I mean, is just two times and I guess it is not terrible difficult, but I wonder if there is a more elegant alternative, or if I am not taking the right approach to html code reuse with JQuery.

Sorry for the long post and thank you before hand to any suggestion!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you execute this code:

```
$("#table-person-info").clone(false)
    .find("*").removeAttr("id")
    .appendTo($("#person-Info-View"));
```

you've gone into a new selection with `find`, so you're appending all the elements with removed IDs, not the original parent table. Try this instead:

```
$("#table-person-info").clone(false)
    .find("*").removeAttr("id").end()
    .appendTo($("#person-Info-View"));
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this may take a little longer to write, with no idea if you're using your own objects or not, but have you thought about using jQuery Templates for your scenario? You could quite easily bind the template to an object and just update the object in the back-end, which would automatically update your table and require far less processing than cloning the full table every time it's updated.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. Besides, jQuery Templates are no longer being actively developed.

Comment: Still, a far more efficient and maintainable way of working. I guess some people don't care about that when using jQuery, it's an annoyance.